# Внутренний EventBus для AspNetCore 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, eventbus

Здравсвуйте, нужно реализовать внутрениий EventBus (не микросервисное взаимодействие на основе например RabbitMq).
 Все издатели пишут на общую шину генерацию события с типизированным данными (MyData)
 Подписчики слушают шину и фильтруют издателей по типу дачных (MyData).
 Желательно чтобы при подписке возвращался IDisposable.
 И издатель мог также отписать всех подписчиков.

Не было времени искать готовые решения поэтому быстро сделал обертку над ReactiveExt

```
public class ReactiveEventBus
{
    public ISubject<object> Bus { get; set; }


    public ReactiveEventBus()
    {
        Bus = new Subject<object>();
    }


    public void Publish<TMessage>(TMessage msg)
    {
        Bus.OnNext(msg);
    }


    public IDisposable Subscribe<TMessage>(Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        return Bus
            .Where(item=> item.GetType() == typeof(TMessage))
            .Subscribe((obj) =>
            {
                var val = (TMessage) obj;
                action(val);
            });
    }
}
```

Т.е. Subscribe срабатывает на всех Publish, для сработки только на нужных событиях, фильтрую через Where по типу.

Тут есть проблема `boxing/unboxing` если TMessage Value типа, т.к. идет преобразование из object `( var val = (TMessage) obj)` перед вызовом самого делегата.
Но у меня события Value врядли будут.

Как сильно сказывается на производительности фильтрация (`Where`) в Rx событиях если много подписчиков и часто публикуются события.

Стоит ли это реализацию заменять на готовые решения (первое что попалось MemBus)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама по себе фильтрация на производительности никак не сказывается. Это же просто условный оператор, пусть и в нескольких обертках...

Важно другое: каждое сообщение в такой схеме направляется сразу всем подписчикам, а потом частью отбрасывается. То есть чем больше подписчиков - тем медленнее работа.

Если вы планируете пересылать через такую шину много данных - лучше создать отдельный Subject для каждого типа сообщений.

---

PS а если вы решите остаться на текущей архитектуре - изучите что делает метод OfType :-)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю OfType.

Comment: я думал создавать Subject для каждого типа, но это дополнительная логика и в публикации и в подписке нуждающаяся в тестах, посмотрел MemBus api очень похож на мой. Но непонятно что у них под капотом). Например метод публикации у них не типизированный void Publish(object message); Буду разбираться спасибо еще раз)